# Add if and else in javascript function based on other jquery function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a jQuery function that will be run when user click a submit button of form is submitted

```
FUNCTION #1
jQuery(function($){

    $('#filter').submit(function() {
        var filter = $('#filter');
        $.ajax({
            url:filter.attr('action'),
            data:filter.serialize(), // form data
            type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                filter.find('button').text('Filtering...'); // changing the button label
            },
            success:function(data){
                filter.find('button').text('Filter'); // changing the button label back
                $('#response').html(data); // insert data
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});


<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
```

I have other script with javascript that run when user click on link with id "link-id".

```
FUNCTION #2

$div1 = $(".div1");
$div2 = $(".div2");

$div1.hide()
$div2.hide()

function showDiv(){
   if(document.getElementById('chk1').checked){ 
       $div1.show()
   } else {
       $div1.hide()
   }
   if(document.getElementById('chk2').checked){
       $div2.show()
   } else {
       $div2.hide()
   }
}
$('#link-id').on('click', showDiv)  

<a id="link-id" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript: void(0)">Go ahead</a>
```

I'd like to add and if and else in the FUNCTION #2 that:

1. if jQuery 'FUNCTION #1' is not submitted (run), javascript 'FUNCTION #2' do something (current code);
2. if user has already click one time on button to run 'FUNCTION #1', the 'FUNCTION #2' shall do other thing.

I'm not expert with javascript code.
Is there a way to made this check?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly the two functions are called from different event which means at different times.

If the scripts are linked (by integrating both in the html) or in one:

Then you could add a global variable that changes in function 1 and is being checked in function 2.

Declaration:

```
let functionOneWasExectuted = false;
```

In function 1:

```
functionOneWasExectuted = true;
```

In function 2:

```
if (functionOneWasExectuted) {
  // code function 1 has been executed before
} else {
  // code function 1 has not been executed before
}
```

If the 2 scripts are not linked in any way let me know and I'll post a different solution :)

Comment: Pretty neat solution, I'd go for this as well :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @marvin. The script are different, but contained in the same html code. For declaration, it shall be added on the first jquey code?

Comment: @marvin I update the code like this: 

FUNCTION #1
let functionOneWasExectuted = false;
jQuery(function($){

and at the end of functions:

return false;
functionOneWasExectuted = true;

And added if and else on functions #2, but doesn't work.